# Primefaces components not showing

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, wildfly

So I'm using WildFly as an application server for my project, and primefaces as a framework alongside with bootsfaces.

My problem is that primefaces components are not rendered at all. I added the primefaces jar to the WEB-INF/lib folder in the webapp and to the build path, I also did add the xml namespace to my webpage.

Now something I noticed, that stroke me as weird, is that the primefaces jar is shown twice in the server deployments dropdown [WildFly Deployments screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLfNZ.png), and that the primefaces jar isn't added to the war structure on my server's deployment files (it is not in the webapp/WEB-INF/lib) [{war}/WEB-INF/lib directory in WildFly deployment folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34pEJ.png). An other weird thing is that I have a folder called "classes", that I didn't add to my structure, inside the {war}/WEB-INF/lib directory (deployments folder) which contains a copy of all of my war's contents including the primefaces jar I can't seem to find in the structure I declared. [the "classes" folder (I don't know where it came from) screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMwN4.png) [contents of the "classes folder" screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvbjX.png) [contents of the "WEB-INF/classes/WEB-INF/lib" folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sJSJ.png).

An image's worth a thousand words, check the pics out please and excuse my poor phrasing.

Thanks for the indulgence, hope to have an answer!

Here's the template code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
        <meta
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no"
            name="viewport" />


        <link type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon"
            href="#{resource['images/favicon.png']}" />

        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/admin/jquery-ui.min.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="vendor/fontawesome/css/all.min.css"
            />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/admin/semantic.min.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/admin/pe-icon-7-stroke.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="vendor/themify-icons/themify-icons.min.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/admin/flash.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/admin/fonts/opensans.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/admin/fonts/alegreyasans.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
            type="text/css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/admin/custom.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/admin/style.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/admin/style.min.css" />

        <h:outputScript name="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
            />
        <h:outputScript name="js/admin/jquery-ui.min.js" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="popper.min.js" />
        <h:outputScript name="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            />
        <h:outputScript name="vendor/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" />
        <h:outputScript name="js/admin/pace.min.js" />
        <h:outputScript name="js/admin/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" />
        <h:outputScript name="js/admin/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js" />
        <h:outputScript name="js/admin/semantic.min.js" />
        <h:outputScript name="js/admin/frame.js" />
        <h:outputScript name="js/admin/custom.js" />
        <h:outputScript name="js/admin/script.js" />
        <title>#{pageTitle}</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body styleClass="sidebar-mini">

        <div class="wrapper">
            <header class="main-header">
                <a href="./index.xhtml" class="logo"> <span class="logo-mini"><img
                        src="#{resource['images/logo.png']}" alt="" /></span> <span
                    class="logo-lg"> <img src="#{resource['images/logo.png']}"
                        alt="" /></span></a>

                <p:menubar>
                    <p:menuitem>
                        <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas"
                            role="button"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="pe-7s-keypad"></span>
                        </a>
                    </p:menuitem>
                    <p:submenu icon="pi pi-cog" style="float:right;">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            OPTIONS
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:menuitem icon="pi pi-user" value="Profile" outcome="profile"
                            includeViewParams="true">
                            <f:param name="id" value="#{sessionBean.user.id}" />
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem icon="pi pi-user-edit" value="Modifier le profile"
                            outcome="edit-profile" includeViewParams="true">
                            <f:param name="id" value="#{sessionBean.user.id}" />
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:divider layout="horizontal" />
                        <p:menuitem icon="pi pi-fw pi-power-off" outcome="logout"
                            value="Se d&#233;connecter" />
                    </p:submenu>

                    <p:submenu icon="pi pi-cog" style="float:right;">
                        <p:badge value="#{sessionBean.fetchNotices().size()}"
                            visible="#{sessionBean.fetchNotices().size() > 0}">
                            <i class="pi pi-bell" />
                        </p:badge>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            NOTIFICATION
                        </f:facet>
                        <ui:repeat var="n" value="#{sessionBean.fetchNotices()}">
                            <p:menuitem value="#{n.title}" outcome="notice"
                                includeViewParams="true">
                                <f:param name="id" value="#{n.id}" />
                            </p:menuitem>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:menubar>
            </header>
            <ui:param name="url" value="" />
            <ui:param name="userRole" value="" />
            <c:if test="#{sessionBean.user.isADoctor()}">
                <ui:param name="userRole" value="de M&#233;decin" />
                <ui:param name="url" value="./doc-sidebar.xhtml" />
                <c:if test="#{sessionBean.user.worksInLab()}">
                    <ui:param name="url" value="./lab-sidebar.xhtml" />
                </c:if>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="#{sessionBean.user.isANurse()}">
                <ui:param name="url" value="./nurse-sidebar.xhtml" />
                <ui:param name="userRole" value="d'Infirmier" />
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="#{sessionBean.user.isPAE()}">
                <ui:param name="url" value="./pae-sidebar.xhtml" />
                <ui:param name="userRole" value="de PAE" />
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="#{sessionBean.user.isAdmin()}">
                <ui:param name="url" value="./admin-sidebar.xhtml" />
                <ui:param name="userRole" value="d'Administrateur" />
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="#{sessionBean.user.worksInLab()}">
                <ui:param name="url" value="./lab-sidebar.xhtml" />
            </c:if>

            <ui:include src="#{url}" />

            <!-- Content -->
            <div class="content-wrapper" style="min-height: 717px;">
                <section class="content-header">
                    <div class="p-l-30 p-r-30">
                        <div class="header-icon">
                            <i class="pe-7s-world"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="header-title">
                            <h1>Tableau de Bord #{userRole}</h1>
                            <small>#{title}</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <ui:insert name="content" />

                <footer class="main-footer">2021 </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: The build system responsible for producing the physical WAR file is clearly corrupt/misconfigured. This is not a JSF/PrimeFaces/WildFly related problem. This is an IDE/build-config/project-structure related problem. Your question cannot be answered as long as you don't tell anything about the way how exactly you built the WAR file. Is it via Eclipse? IntelliJ? Maven? Ant? Or is it even manually in CLI? Etc.

Comment: And don't load your own jQuery, PrimeFaces will load it for you. Loading multiple instances will cause issues.